# java how can i check a file name and open with FileResource auxFr = new FileResource("/testing/yob" + auxYear + "short.csv");

Tags: java, file

Using [FileResource](http://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/course5/doc/javadoc/edu/duke/FileResource.html) from edu.duke, how can I check if the file exists before opening it like this?

```
FileResource auxFr = new FileResource("/testing/yob" + auxYear + "short.csv");
```

Comment: What exacting are you trying to do? Do you want to check whether it exists or you want to read the file?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it concise. Consider adding any error messages you may be seeing and saying what you'd like to do if the file is not found.

Comment: Im trying to check if the file exists and late open the file FileResource from edu.duke library but                                                                                
String resourceName = "/testing/yob" + auxYear + "short.csv";
            File auxFile = new File(resourceName);
            if (auxFile.exists()){ // is false is not working and the files are there, my program and class are in /user/..../babybirths and my files to open in /babybirths/testing ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use File api to check whether file exists or not and then do whatever action you need to do with edu.duke library. Here you go how the code should look like

```
String resourceName = "/testing/yob" + auxYear + "short.csv";
File file = new File(resourceName);
if(file.exists()){
   FileResource auxFr = new FileResource(file);
}
```

Comment: yea what is there that I am missing?

Comment: look good but in if (file.exists()) is false, my program and my class are in /user/...../babybirths and my files to test the program are in /testing so is it correct resourceName = "/testing/yob" + auxYear + "short.csv" why is not working, cant find the files in this folder???

Comment: Not getting what is the issue this should work.. btw the resource name should be absolute path to the file and not relative folder path..

Comment: How can I get absolute path... is a Mac and files are "/Desktoop/coursera/week4_babybirths/babybirths/testing" but I dont know if is it absolute path or is "c://Desktoop/coursera/week4_babybirths/babybirths/testing" or I how can I get this ????

Comment: If you are using mac then go into console and go to ur file directory and use `pwd` command where your file is located the output will give you something like **/Users/<ur_system_name>/Desktop/coursera/week4_babybirths/babybirths/testing**

Comment: please if you have a Mac send me a picture because I cant find this option ??

Comment: String resourceName = "/Users/Tato/Desktop/coursera/wee4_babybirths/babybirths/testing/yob" + auxYear + "short.csv";
            File auxFile = new File(resourceName);
            if (auxFile.exists()){ // function exists() is false I dont know why???

Comment: Have you used terminal in your mac?

Comment: ok i have window open with terminal application.. a black window with > what can i do??

Comment: Ok thank you finally I got the solution.... some was wrong in the String like was String resourceName = "/Users/User/Desktop/coursera/week4_babybirths/babybirths/testing/yob" + auxYear + "short.csv"; // work Users/User is the same like Users/Tato ??? but is working

Comment: is my first time here ,,,, where I can give a thumbs up and accept your answer let me know thank you so much

Comment: Ok no issues :) You will get hang of it after using it for sometime.

Answer (score 0):

There is an api File.exists() which you can use to check if the file exist. Something like:

```
File file = new File("/testing/yob" + auxYear + "short.csv");
if(file.exists()) { 
  System.out.println("Exists"); 
}
```

Comment: look good but in if (file.exists()) is false, my program and my class are in /user/...../babybirths and my files to test the program are in /testing so is it correct resourceName = "/testing/yob" + auxYear + "short.csv" why is not working, cant find the files in this folder???

Comment: You have to provide the absolute path. No matter which OS you are using, you can get the full path by digging into the folder/file details. Generally, it is available in the options in Right Click on windows.

Comment: i cant make a question again ,,, but i have this problem,,, dont read the first row (record) i dont know